# Creating unviewable parts of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I prevent a user from seeing a certain parts of the page. My goal was to make a huge maze within the browser (so big that the path is big as the width of the browswer screen); the user has to navigate using the scroll bar or any other scrolling method until they find the end of the maze. Making the maze is not the challenge, but to prevent the user from crossing over the boundaries is where I am having trouble.

My thought process is to make objects/areas on the page that block the user from continuing to move in that particular direction. Maybe the user can see 50px of the block/area before he can not go any further? I have never seen this done and I was curious to know if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make the whole thing into a grid of DIVs and show/hide them as necessary?  It might be helpful if we can see what you have already.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that won’t be that answer you were looking for, but if you have some experience in graphics, you can try to use [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) library to generate the maze with canvas or webgl. You can use point light to lighten only small part of the maze. Other part can have something like “fog of war”.

If you are not interested in canvas/webgl, then you can try to use an overlay png image with transparent hole in it. Width and height of the image has to be screen.height*2 x screen.width*2 (not sure about that, but that is how I see it). That image should be on top of whole maze. It’ll hide whole maze except for that under transparent area. And your starting point should be in the center of that transparent area. Then you need to move that image along with user input (arrow keys, mouse, whatever). Alternatively, you can move maze itself. This way overlay image can have screen dimetions.

These are two option that came to my mind.